# How would I go about creating a new data frame that has the unique values of a a column and it counts them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Let's suppose I have a python data frame that looks something like this:

```
Factor_1    Factor_2    Factor_3   Factor_4   Factor_5
   A           B           A          Nan       Nan
   B           D           F          A         Nan
   F           A           D          B          A
```

Something like this in which I have 5 columns that have different factors. I would like to create a column that counts how many of this factors appear in the dataframe so the expected output would be something like this:

```
Factor   Count
  A        5
  B        3
  D        2
  F        2
 Nan       3
```

I've been trying to use a groupby but havent been able to get the  desired output, using somehting like this.

```
df['Counts'] = df.groupby(['Factor_1'])['Factor_2', 'Factor_3', 'Factor_4', 'Factor_5'].transform('count')
```

I actually don't know what else to do so if some one could help me it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.stack(dropna=False).value_counts(dropna=False)

A      5
B      3
NaN    3
D      2
F      2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another potential solution using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.melt().value.value_counts()
```

**Output**:

```
A      5
B      3
Nan    3
F      2
D      2
```